# Fake classes using TypeMock

Tags: unit-testing, typemock, typemock-isolator

We are migrating from MOQ to Typemock. In MOQ we've a functionality of getting a proxy class from the interface, we want to achieve the same from typemock. Actually our requirement is something like this, we are using Ninject IoC/DI pattern in our application and wants to enjoy the benefits of it in unit testing.

We want to use Ninject kernel to register the interface with FakeClass or more appropriately ProxyClass. The syntax is somewhat this

```
kernel.Bind(interface).to(class)
```

and we want

```
kernel.Bind(interface).to(fakeclass)
```

In MOQ we do this like this

```
var mock=new Mock(interface)
```

and `mock.Object()` method gives us the fake class.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a fake object, use the `Isolate.Fake.Instance<T>()` method:

```
Interface fake = Isolate.Fake.Instance<Interface>();
```

Then you can just use that fake instance:

```
kernel.Bind(interface).to(fake);
```

This was from [this blog entry](http://blog.typemock.com/2011/05/basic-unit-testing-with-typemock.html)

Comment: Though I have to question the wisdom of moving to a new framework if you don't know the most basic usage of the framework, and can't figure it out from the documentation.  How was the decision to move to TypeMock made if not research into its suitablity was done?  And if that research was done, how can you not know how to to the most basic function of a mocking framework.

Comment: Thanks but it'll works exactly as like this                  kernel.Bind(interface).toConstant(fake);